# ASP.NET Web API - test error : an error has occurred - how to fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

My ASP.NET Web API project works fine but when I want to run it on a server I can't pull the data. I'm using an Azure SQL database, I don't have a problem on the local server.

I can't figure out why am I getting this error

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: an error has occurred.   
 The given header was not found

 StackTrace    
 at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.GetValues(String name)    
 at RayTech.API.Security.ApiKeyHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\Enesray\Source\Repos\RayTechWebApi\RayTech.API\Security\ApiKeyHandler.cs:line 23 at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     
 at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
```

`web.config`:

```
<add name="RayTechDbEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/RayTechModel.csdl|res://*/RayTechModel.ssdl|res://*/RayTechModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*******;initial catalog=RayTechDb;user id=********;password=********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"  
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Links:

- Screenshot on local server postman: https://i.hizliresim.com/4r24ie8.jpg
- Screenshot online site: https://i.hizliresim.com/gt6idph.jpg
- Google Chrome: https://i.hizliresim.com/tvhw63j.jpg

Comment: when using azure database, you should set the firewall for IP, when you test locally and everything's fine always means your code is correct. so after publish it to azure, the IP is different so you need to add that IP to your azure database, just check it if you miss it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using azure database, `setting the firewall` for the IP of Azure web app is required so that Azure web app can access the database.

Answer (score 0):

- connection string of azure SQL database is in the following format :

```
    Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

- I think your connection string is not compliant with the above format. you can get your connection directly from portal under connection string tab.

[image]

Refer this [msdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/develop-app-that-queries-azure-sql/4-connect-aspnet-to-azure-sql) on sql databse